# ruby on rails for static websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been using Ruby on Rails for a while now and I'm really comfortable with it.

Lately I've also been using rails for simple static websites that consist of about 10 pages and some form handlers & mailers.

Now I'm wondering the following:

1. Is it overkill to use Rails for such sites with regards to memory usage?
2. What would be the cons for using Rails for such websites?
3. What would you guys suggest as an alternative?

I thank you all in advance for your replies.

Regards

Comment: even if this is overkill, you still get the benefit of the rails framework in the form of security, modularity and custom routing.  I'd say the benefits far outweigh the cons of the additional overhead (unless you've identified that as a problem)

Comment: @chris: static html files are more secure than ruby on rails (or any other dynamic solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most important aspects of web design is the ability to expand/update/read the code. If you're most comfortable in RoR, use RoR. It's not overkill, especially because you can get extremely good test coverage with such a small website. If you or any person that inherits the website ever wants to add model code, it would be extremely easy.

BTW, I would highly suggest checking out the [high voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem from thoughtbot. Very good for hosting static pages.

Comment: You are completely correct. Will keep using Rails for simple static sites. Will try out high voltage also. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) please. It's a wondering tool for static websites on Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Although, Rails has higher memory foot print, since it gives you a lot of development power it is not an overkill. The pros are far more than cons so if you are comfortable with Rails use it for static pages too. You may need to update these pages to more advanced sites and applications at some point and with rails you will always have the option.

Comment: The easy expandability is certainly a big pro with Rails. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

There really aren't many alternatives that are much simpler than RoR. In terms of memory usage, you could use PHP to fix that issue, but who wants to use PHP? No one, that's who :)

You could take a quick look at something like Node.js + the Express framework. Overall Node with Express is pretty different from RoR (it's purely javascript), but the way you generate views, etc is pretty similar.

I haven't don't too much in it, just some simple sites, but with little to no data-handling, you aren't going to be digging into the complicated stuff anyways. This framework would fix your memory woes completely.

You can look at it quickly here:

http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/introduction-to-express/

In my honest opinion, I would just stick with RoR. It's super easy and relatively lightweight in everything but the memory footprint, but if memory is REALLY that much of an issue, then give Node a try, it's fun. Some people love it, some hate it. It's still fun to learn.

Comment: I will check out Node.js. Heard interesting this about it so far. Thanks for your answer

Comment: No problem man. It's a bit daunting and confusing at first. There are plenty of youtube videos, sites, etc that have good beginner tutorials to show you how to setup node, generate an express application, etc.